# Ambiguos "Error: NEXUS__UNKNOWN__TYPE was already defined and imported as a type" error in nexus graphql

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo, nexus

I'm getting the following error when using nexus to define a graphql schema with apollo-server.

`Error: NEXUS__UNKNOWN__TYPE was already defined and imported as a type`

The stacktrace doesn't give much information as to where the issue is occurring or to what the problem is. The project has 20+ models and dozens of resolvers so it's quite hard to debug.

```
Error: NEXUS__UNKNOWN__TYPE was already defined and imported as a type, check the docs for extending types
    at extendError (/Users/username/Documents/folder/folder/graphq-nexus-prisma-api/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:1744:2)
    at SchemaBuilder.addType (/Users/username/Documents/folder/folder/graphq-nexus-prisma-api/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:603:8)
    at SchemaBuilder.missingType (/Users/username/Documents/folder/folder/graphq-nexus-prisma-api/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:1212:5)
    at SchemaBuilder.getOrBuildType (/Users/username/Documents/folder/folder/graphq-nexus-prisma-api/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:1540:4)
    at SchemaBuilder.getOutputType (/Users/username/Documents/folder/folder/graphq-nexus-prisma-api/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:1471:10)
    at SchemaBuilder.buildOutputField (/Users/username/Documents/folder/folder/graphq-nexus-prisma-api/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:1349:52)
    at /Users/username/Documents/folder/folder/graphq-nexus-prisma-api/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:1307:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at SchemaBuilder.buildOutputFields (/Users/username/Documents/folder/folder/graphq-nexus-prisma-api/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:1306:7)
    at fields (/Users/username/Documents/folder/folder/graphq-nexus-prisma-api/node_modules/nexus/src/builder.ts:1009:33)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I got the same error message and it is not helpful. I had to undo recent changes one-by-one to determine the cause.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, but it was because I removed some exports. I'm not exactly sure what caused it, but I basically have a file that exports all of my graphql modules. E.g.

```
// graphql/modules/index.ts

export * from './file-a';
export * from './file-b';
```

When I removed the second export line, I started getting the error. I'm probably using some of the types defined in `file-b` somewhere else, and that's somehow causing the error. Anyway, adding the line back in fixed it (I had removed it by accident anyway).

**UPDATE**

I also go this by referencing some arg types that didn't exist (typo). For example:

```js
args: {
  where: arg({ type: 'ConversationsWhereInput' }),
  orderBy: arg({ type: 'ConversationsOrderByInput', list: true }),
},
```

The `s` in `Conversations` shouldn't be there. It should be:

```js
args: {
  where: arg({ type: 'ConversationWhereInput' }),
  orderBy: arg({ type: 'ConversationOrderByInput', list: true }),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It could have been much helpful if you could elaborate what did you do before this error happened.

I just came up with this error exactly as same as what you got and for me it was because I just accidentally changed the `name` for `objectType` of typeDef.

For instance, the `name` for the `FollowUserResult` was actually `FollowResult` and after I changed the `name`, the whole mutation resolvers related to this `objectType` became wrong.

```js
export const FollowUserResult = objectType({
  name: "FollowUserResult", // It was originally "FollowResult"
  definition(t) {
    t.nonNull.boolean("ok");
    t.string("error");
  },
});
```

You may check on this again. Once you got those correct, delete the `schema.graphql` file and generate the new `schema.graphql` file.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was using the incorrect Node version. My project didn't have a .nvrmc file (yet) so I was using Node 10 on a project that uses Node 14. So after switching to the correct Node version this error went away

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I incorrectly specified an unknown type in the `type` attribute of an extension to the `Query` type.  More specifically:

```js
export const CoursesQuery = extendType({
  type: "Query",
  definition(t) {
    t.field("myQuery", {
      type: InvalidType,  // <--- Changing InvalidType to the correct type fixed the error
      async resolve(_parent, _args, ctx) {
        return ...
      },
    });
  },
});
```

The error disappeared after I changed `InvalidType` to the correct type and restarted the server.